# How do get my css style sheet to work the same in IE9 as it does in IE8 and other browsers?

Tags: css, web-development, internet-explorer-9

I am developing the following website and just discovered that the styling of the navigation does not work well in IE9 but is great in IE8 and other browsers - how do sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also set this as an HTTP header. If you are using Apache you can place this in an .htaccess file in your route directory to accomplish the same thing:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=8"
```

Answer (score 1):

or simply you can use  CSS - Conditional comments for IE

http://www.css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks.shtml

which will be quiet simple if you are a newbie
hope it helps.